# Show how set $\mathbb{R^2}$ ith custom operations defines a set over R

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm stuck on one of my homework questions from linear algebra class.

Show that the set $\mathbb{R^2}$, equipped with custom operations
$(x_1,y_1)+(x_2 ,y_2)=(x_1+x_2+1,y_1+y_2−1)$

$λ ⋅ (x,y)=(λx+λ−1,λy−λ+1)$

defines a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Would I prove that the zero vector exists, and closure exists under addition and multiplication? Thanks.

Comment: You have to check all the axioms (generally about 10) for a vector space.

Comment: "Closure" is built in to the definitions, and so is not a concern. The things you need to show are [listed in the table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).